# Merge Array of Arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I need to merge this Array of Arrays in this order

```
[
  [
    { x: 0, y: 0, color: 12 },
    { x: 1, y: 0, color: 12 },
    { x: 2, y: 0, color: 12 },
    { x: 3, y: 0, color: 12 }
  ],
  [
    { x: 3, y: 1, color: 12 },
    { x: 2, y: 1, color: 12 },
    { x: 1, y: 1, color: 12 },
    { x: 0, y: 1, color: 12 }
  ],
  [
    { x: 0, y: 2, color: 12 },
    { x: 1, y: 2, color: 12 },
    { x: 2, y: 2, color: 12 },
    { x: 3, y: 2, color: 12 }
  ],
  [
    { x: 3, y: 3, color: 12 },
    { x: 2, y: 3, color: 12 },
    { x: 1, y: 3, color: 12 },
    { x: 0, y: 3, color: 12 }
  ]
]
```

Expexted Output:

```
[
  
    { x: 0, y: 0, color: 12 },
    { x: 1, y: 0, color: 12 },
    { x: 2, y: 0, color: 12 },
    { x: 3, y: 0, color: 12 },
    { x: 3, y: 1, color: 12 },
    { x: 2, y: 1, color: 12 },
    { x: 1, y: 1, color: 12 },
    { x: 0, y: 1, color: 12 },
    { x: 0, y: 2, color: 12 },
    { x: 1, y: 2, color: 12 },
    { x: 2, y: 2, color: 12 },
    { x: 3, y: 2, color: 12 }, 
    { x: 3, y: 3, color: 12 },
    { x: 2, y: 3, color: 12 },
    { x: 1, y: 3, color: 12 },
    { x: 0, y: 3, color: 12 }
  
]
```

I tried

```
    let res = []
    for (let i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {

        res = [...all[i]]
    }
```

The all array is the first array of arrays.
I cant "manually" merge them like this const mergeResult = [...array1, ...array2]; because i dont know how many arrays their will be in the array.
The Array count and(in this case 4 arrays) and entries in the array will be the same

Comment: You can just use [`arr.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).

Comment: This comment just saved me a lot of headache. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Array#flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat):

```js
const obj = [
  [
    { x: 0, y: 0, color: 12 },
    { x: 1, y: 0, color: 12 },
    { x: 2, y: 0, color: 12 },
    { x: 3, y: 0, color: 12 }
  ],
  [
    { x: 3, y: 1, color: 12 },
    { x: 2, y: 1, color: 12 },
    { x: 1, y: 1, color: 12 },
    { x: 0, y: 1, color: 12 }
  ],
  [
    { x: 0, y: 2, color: 12 },
    { x: 1, y: 2, color: 12 },
    { x: 2, y: 2, color: 12 },
    { x: 3, y: 2, color: 12 }
  ],
  [
    { x: 3, y: 3, color: 12 },
    { x: 2, y: 3, color: 12 },
    { x: 1, y: 3, color: 12 },
    { x: 0, y: 3, color: 12 }
  ]
]

const result = obj.flat()
console.log(result)
```